# Need help for the build path problem in my eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have a small question regarding the build path of the eclipse.
I have checked out code from svn and then i was trying to edit some of the java files and i dont know why it does not compile and complains and givens the following error message

"compilation util is not on a build path of a java project "
I am not sure why i get this..
I have the following things in my build path 
i have installed jdk in the follwoing directory 
c:\program files\java\jdk...

then i have the following things on my java build path
eclipsehome --c:\eclipse
java_home--c:\program files\java\jdk...

Can some one please help me out in this..

Thanks,
Swati

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, it's not set to be a Java project. A Java project has a little "J" on the project folder. Try closing that project then tell it to create a new Java project from existing source, point it at the top-level directory and see what happens. You might need to delete your current project file.